# atoi() for 2 dimensional array

Tags: c, 2d, atoi

If I have a 2D char array:

```
char tempoArray[2][3]={{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
```

How can I convert each entire row to one integer value using `atoi()` so that

```
printf("val1 %d\nval2 %d", val1, val2);
```

Will give me:

> 123
>
> 456

Comment: You don't. I mean you don't use `atoi` to do it. Instead you use normal decimal arithmetic (like `1 * 100` to get `100`, etc.).

Comment: Or if it's just for the output, why not print the three small integers next to each other without spacing between them, then it will look correct.

Comment: `char tempoArray[2][4]={{'1','2','3',0x00}, {'4','5','6', 0x00}};` then `val1= atoi(tempoArray[0]); val2= atoi(tempoArray[1]);`

Comment: You could do this at compile-time with X macros. But the code would then look really evil. Something like `#define MAGIC(i1, i2, i3) (i1 ## i2 ## i3)
  #define X(i1, i2, i3) MAGIC(i1, i2, i3)
  printf("val1 %d\nval2 %d", VALUES );
  #undef X`. Not recommended!

Comment: @LP do you feel that `0x00` is somehow "more zero" than `0`? Since it's characters you're bulding, `'\0'` would communicate slightly more. But a plain `0` is fine.

Comment: @LPs That's a neat trick. :-)

Comment: @unwind Professional deformation ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
char tempoArray[2][3]={{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
```

your array contains small integer values like `1`, `2`, and `3`.

`atoi` operates on strings, which are arrays of characters.  For example, the string

```
"123"
```

consists of the three characters `'1'`, `'2'`, and `'3'`, plus a trailing null character `'\0'`.

But the digit characters `'1'`, `'2'`, and `'3'` do *not* have the values 1, 2, and 3!  If you hadn't known this, I encourage you to run this little program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("character '1' has value %d, number 1 has value %d\n", '1', 1);
    printf("character '2' has value %d, number 2 has value %d\n", '2', 2);
    printf("character '3' has value %d, number 3 has value %d\n", '3', 3);
}
```

Since the rows of your array are *not* strings (they are not arrays of useful character values, and they are not null-terminated), it is not possible to simply call `atoi()` on them.

Since the arrays contain integer values already, the most straightforward thing to do would be to do the arithmetic yourself, like this:

```
int i, j;
int val;

for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    val = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        val = 10 * val + tempoArray[i][j];
    }
    printf("val: %d\n", val);
}
```

If you really, really wanted to call `atoi`, you would have to construct an actual string from each array row, like this:

```
char tmpstring[4];

for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        tmpstring[j] = tempoArray[i][j] + 48;  /* +48 to convert dig to char */
    }
    tmpstring[j] = '\0';

    val = atoi(tmpstring);

    printf("val: %d\n", val);
}
```

As you can see, this is more work, and more confusing.

One more point.  To make it clear what kind of conversion was going on, I wrote

```
        tmpstring[j] = tempoArray[i][j] + 48;  /* +48 to convert dig to char */
```

But in real code I would never write this, because that "magic number" 48 is too obscure.  In real code I would always write

```
        tmpstring[j] = tempoArray[i][j] + '0';
```

By definition, the value of the character `'0'` is exactly the right value to add to convert the number 1 to the character `'1'`, the number 2 to the character `'2'`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you really insist on using `atoi` you must transform each digit to a `char` first (e.g. by adding `'0'`). Also you must zero terminate the string.

I recommend using arithmetic, here. Just loop over the array and use the transition: `x = 10*x + array[i]`, initializing `x` to `0`.